# return true when first async method returns true

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

Lets say i have the following code

```
public async Task<bool> PingAddress(string ipAddress)
{
    return await DoSomeThing(10) || await DoSomeThing(11) || await DoSomeThing(12);

}

private async Task<bool> DoSomeThing(int input)
{
    //Do some thing and return true or false.
}
```

How would i convert the `return await DoSomeThing(10) || await DoSomeThing(11) || await DoSomeThing(12);` to run in parallel and return true when first returns true and if all return false then return false!

Comment: So you want if `await DoSomthing(11)` returns a true first you don't want to have to wait for `10` or `12` to return a true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an asynchronous "Any" operation on a collection of tasks.

```
public static async Task<bool> LogicalAny(this IEnumerable<Task<bool>> tasks)
{
    var remainingTasks = new HashSet<Task<bool>>(tasks);
    while (remainingTasks.Any())
    {
        var next = await Task.WhenAny(remainingTasks);
        if (next.Result)
            return true;
        remainingTasks.Remove(next);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This works great but is there any way to stop the rest of the tasks when i found one that returns true?

Comment: @Peter That would require cooperative cancellation.  The tasks would all need to be given a cancellation token that you cancel when the result of this operation finished, and those tasks would all need to check for cancellation periodically.

Comment: when you say "tasks would all need to check for cancellation periodically" is this done in the .net framework for me? as all my DoSomething method does is await a method defined in the WinRT library?

Comment: @Peter No, it's not done for you.  That's what makes the cancellation cooperative.  Either that method was specifically designed to support cancellation, and specifically checks for cancellation in its definition periodically, or it doesn't, and there isn't really anything you can do.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `await Task.WhenAny` to determine when the tasks return, and return true when the first one completes.

This typically looks like:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<bool>> 
                {
                   DoSomething(10), 
                   DoSomething(11), 
                   DoSomething(12)                        
                };

while (tasks.Any())
{
     var t = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
     if (t.Result) return true;

     tasks.Remove(t);
}

// If you get here, all the tasks returned false...
```

Comment: Well the first one that completes could return false, in that case i need to wait for the next to complete and check if it returned true and so on...

Comment: also task.Any() should be tasks.Any()

Answer (score -3):

You need to use a WaitHandle. Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdykks7z.aspx)

Comment: correct me if im wrong but WaitHandle.WaitAny will stop on the first task that is completed weather it returns true or not...